# im new and python wont let me install the pafy module or the vlc module so i can do my first project, how to fix?

Tags: python, module

Hi I'm new and am trying to see how Python Modules work but whenever I do `import pafy` it says *modulenotfounderror* and when I do  `install pafy` it says that the I in install is a *syntax error*.
so how do I fix this? do I download something? and I know the answer might seem obvious but this is my first time using one and those two are the only answers im getting, so help a brother out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the command line to `pip install pafy`

For more information see [the pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/).

Alternatively, if you want to install it from a python file, you can make one and run it with this code:

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'pafy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip` from command line.
Assuming you've installed python from the official website (https://python.org), pip should be pre-installed, and you can simply run command line (hotkey `win + r` and type in `cmd` on windows) and type in `pip install <module name here>`, which in your case would be pafy.

Use ([this website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/getting-started/)) for more info, it provides pip commands for macOS, Windows and Linux